# Firefox extension to view/manage all keyboard shortcuts, including those set by extensions?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-addons

Every extension ever created wants to use Ctrl+shift+s for something, and I've had other problems with re-enabling a specific extension's shortcut after it's been clobbered.

Is there an extension that shows which shortcuts other extensions have set, and which one has "won" that key combination? It would be great if it could also manage them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KeyConfig](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi) can show you all your current shortcuts and allows you to manage them. It won't show you which has precedence, but it helps in removing overlaps:

[image]

As you can see, the keyboard shortcut for "Inspect Element" (which is for the Firebug add-on) can be configured, along with Firefox builtins.

Comment: Thanks! Strange for an non-abandoned app to be missing from the mozilla addons site - I wonder why. Anyway, this does what I need. Just sort by Shortcut to see what else is vying for that key.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: Limited solution only.

i.e. I cannot change "switch text direction" from Ctrl+Shift+X to RCtrl+RShift for RTL text and LCtrl+LShift for LTR text like most windows applications.